# typeahead bloodhound display key in textbox instead if value

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I'm trying to remotely fetch the data as "My name ".
I'm using this format as the display text.
Now, in my situation is, I need to use only the email address in text box selected and not the name of the user.

How can this be achieved? Also, I'm unable to increase the no. of suggestions fetched from the server.

Library used: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

Code Snippet:

```
var filteredUsers = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('display'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: 'ajax/team/search-member.php?keyword=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY',
            filter: function(list) {
                return $.map(list, function(response) { return { email: response.email, display: response.display }; });
            }

        }
    });

    filteredUsers.initialize();

    $('#remote .typeahead').typeahead({minLength: 2, limit: 10}, {
        limit: 10,
        name: 'filteredUsers',
        displayKey: 'display',
        source: filteredUsers.ttAdapter()
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the email addresses to perform the search ? Or do you want to display them in the suggestions list ?

Comment: in my suggestions list i'm getting the data proper as i want to display to the users in format "name <email>".
But, when they click on it (select one suggestion), I need the text box to have only the email address, and not the combination i.e. "name <email>"